# Solving $\sin(5x) = \sin(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

If I have an equation:

$$\sin(5x) = \sin(x)$$

In what case can I equate $$5x = x$$

Is it only when there is a multiply of $2\pi n$ on either side, where n is any integer so

$$ 5x = x+2\pi n$$

Also with this method can I get every possible solution or does that not work?

I know I can use the sine addition formula but I want to see others I way I can solve this.

Comment: The easiest way would be to write that $\sin(x)=\sin(y) \iff x=y+2\pi n \vee x=\pi-y+2\pi n$.

Comment: @Galc127 Is this always the case, even for cos(x)=cos(y)

Comment: No, $\cos(x)=\cos(y) \iff x=y+2\pi n \vee x=-y+2\pi n$. It comes from the following identities - $\sin(\pi-y)=\sin(y),\cos(-y)=\cos(y)$.

Comment: Related (and very recent) question: ["Finding roots of $\sin(x)=\sin(ax)$ without resorting to complex analysis"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1697599/409).

Comment: @Galc127 thank you very much, not sure why they don't teach this to us at school..

Comment: @Blue thank you very much blue! :D

Comment: @Galc127 I was wondering is there is a proof to sin(x)=sin(y) thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find this useful:

$$
\sin(A)=\sin(B) \iff A=B +n2\pi\ \mbox{ or }\ A=\pi-B +n2\pi,
$$
with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. 
$$
\cos(A)=\cos(B) \iff A=B +n2\pi\ \mbox{ or }\ A=-B +n2\pi,
$$
with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So you need to solve two equations separately:
$$5x=x+n2\pi$$
and 
$$5x=\pi-x+n2\pi.$$
Good luck `:)`

---

**Edit:**
One way to prove 
$$
\sin(x)=\sin(y) \iff x=y +n2\pi\ \mbox{ or }\ x=\pi-y +n2\pi,
$$
is to just verify the solutions work, using a consequence of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):
$$\sin(x)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{ix}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix}}{2i}.$$
So, here we go:
$$
\sin(x)=\sin(y) \iff \frac{\mathrm{e}^{ix}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix}}{2i}=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{iy}-\mathrm{e}^{-iy}}{2i} \iff \mathrm{e}^{ix}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix}=\mathrm{e}^{iy}-\mathrm{e}^{-iy}.
$$

- Now note that $x=y+n2\pi$ is indeed a solution:
  $$\mathrm{e}^{ix}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix}=\mathrm{e}^{i(y+n2\pi)}-\mathrm{e}^{-i(y+n2\pi)}=\mathrm{e}^{iy}\mathrm{e}^{in2\pi}-\mathrm{e}^{-iy}\mathrm{e}^{-in2\pi}=\mathrm{e}^{iy}-\mathrm{e}^{-iy}
  $$
- and that $x=\pi-y+n2\pi$ is indeed a solution:
  $$\mathrm{e}^{ix}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix}=\mathrm{e}^{i(\pi-y+n2\pi)}-\mathrm{e}^{-i(\pi-y+n2\pi)}=\mathrm{e}^{-iy}\mathrm{e}^{i(2n+1)\pi}-\mathrm{e}^{iy}\mathrm{e}^{-i(2n+1)\pi}=\mathrm{e}^{iy}-\mathrm{e}^{-iy}.$$

The last equalities use $\mathrm{e}^{in\pi}$ is equal to $1$ if $n$ is even and equal to $-1$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: What is the proof for why this method works?

Comment: For me it is intuitively clear when you look at the graph of such functions. For example, if you draw $\sin(x)$ yourself for $x\in[0,\pi]$, you can see that for every $x$ and $\pi-x$ the graph has the same value. I hope this is understandable, I don't have time to draw the picture right now. Maybe someone else can? Or I'll do it when I have more time `:)`

Comment: btw, are these formulas not in your text book / learned to you at school? (judging from an earlier comment you made.) That's a shame `:(`

Comment: nope! :( , I even asked my teacher if sin(xyz) = sin(xyz), in what cases are they equal to each other and he had no clue.. he just said to use the sine addition formula..

Comment: That's a shame. Anyway, I've added a proof for $\sin(x)=\sin(y)$, but it uses complex exponents, don't know if you're familiar with them. If there are any questions, please let me know!

Comment: Thank you for the "complex" way of proofing this. Can you also explain to me with elementary trig functions instead of complex? Sorry if I'm bothering :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36999/discussion-between-dydxx-and-eric-s).

Comment: I can't think of a such a proof, and I couldn't find it on the internet either. I guess most text books either just claim the result, or prove it using complex exponents, depending on the level. - But again, drawing the graph gives you the right intuition.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you so much for the extended help! :)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\sin x=\sin y$. Then for the cosine there are just two possibilities, since $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x=1-\sin^2y=\cos^2y$: either $\cos x=\cos y$ or $\cos x=-\cos y$.

In the first case, the angles $x$ and $y$ must differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$; in the second case, if we write $z=\pi-y$, we have $\sin z=\sin y$ and $\cos z=-\cos y$, so $\sin x=\sin z$ and $\cos x=\cos z$, so we're in the above case and we conclude $x$ differs from $z=\pi-y$ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Therefore the equation $\sin x=\sin y$ is solved by the two cases

- $x=y+2k\pi$
- $x=\pi-y+2k\pi$

In your particular case the first one becomes $5x=x+2k\pi$ that can also be written
$$
x=k\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and the second case becomes $5x=\pi-x+2k\pi$, that is,
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{6}+k\frac{\pi}{3}
$$

Some solutions, for instance $\pi/2$ appear in both sets.

---

With a similar reasoning you can solve $\cos x=\cos y$ with the two sets

- $x=y+2k\pi$
- $x=-y+2k\pi$

If you have $\sin x=\cos y$, you reduce it to the previous cases by noting it is the same as $\sin x=\sin(\pi/2-y)$ (or $\cos(\pi/2-x)=\cos y$).

Answer (score 2):

You may also use this identity:
\begin{align}
\sin(5x)-\sin(x)&=2\sin(\frac{5x-x}{2})\cos(\frac{5x+x}{2})\\
&=2\sin(2x)\cos(3x)\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin5x=\sin x\Rightarrow 5x=x+n.2\pi$$ **or** $$5x=\pi-x+n.2\pi$$ 
which leads to solutions of the form $$x=n.\frac{\pi}{2}\cup x=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

Apart from trivial solution ($x=y+2n\pi$), you can see others geometrically from looking at the [Unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle):

[image]

For angle $x$ in $1$st quadrant you have $y$ from $2$nd quadrant such $y = \pi - x$ which gives you $\sin x =\sin y$. Taking periodicity into account, you have

$$
y = \pi - x + 2n\pi
$$

Similarly for $x$ being from $3$rd quadrant you see that it will have same $\sin$ value as $y$ from $4$th quadrant satisfying $2\pi - y = x - \pi$, which is just the same equality as above in disguise (put $n=1$).

So overall you have
$$
y = x + 2n\pi
$$
$$
y = \pi - x + 2n\pi
$$

for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now just plug in your $x$ and $5x$ for $x$ and $y$ to get your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative solution: expand the LHS:
$$16\sin^5 x - 20\sin^3 x + 5\sin x = \sin(5x) = \sin x,$$
and $s = \sin x$ is a solution of
$$(16s^4 - 20s^2 + 4)s = 16s^5 - 20s^3 + 4s = 0.$$

Comment: You're joking, aren't you?

Comment: "better"? Are you sure?

Comment: Just casually solve the quintic :/

Comment: @egreg, is really so difficult to solving a *biquadratic*?

Comment: @K.Power, the quintic has a linear factor and the quartic factor is *biquadratic*.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla This is the *worst* method. Please, try the same with $\sin97x=\sin33x$ and we'll see. Then compare with the “$x=y$ or $x=\pi-y$” method.

Comment: I don't really have  a problem with saying that this is an **alternative** solution, but it is objectivelly **not** better.

Comment: @egreg,  this method is surely bad for $\sin97x = \sin33x$, but not for *this* case.

Comment: @5xum, I've changed the word.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla So I've retracted the downvote.

Comment: I've also retracted the close vote. Still, a warning to the OP: This alternative solution works in *this particular case*, because the quintic polynomial is still easy to solve. It can get really ugly really fast if you have bigger coefficients instead of $5$.

Comment: I have not retracted the downvote, as I think this answer only blurs thing for the OP. As he's still getting familiar with the $"x=y$ or $x=\pi-y"$ stuff, I see no need to complicate things for him by throwing in an otherwise useless approach...

Comment: Just to follow your approach, say you do solve the quintic for $s$ and you arrive at $\sin(x)=a$, with $a$ some (possibly beastly) expression, then what? Surely you can't rewrite to $\sin(x)=\sin(...)$ and use the identity you tried to avoid... So, how do you continue when you have $s$?

Comment: @EricS., $s = 0,\pm 1/2,\pm 1,\implies x = \arcsin s = 0,\pm\pi/6,\pm\pi/2$  in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ and now use the periodicity of both functions.